# Rails - how to check first radio input from the list?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, radio-button

From the database I am loading data, which are displayed in the form (`form_for`) as the radio inputs.
Support Rails any way, how to always check the first radio input in the group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to the first radio_button:

```
:checked => true
```

Although if you are using it from a model I'd highly recommend [simple form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/)